# Is there a way to use the USB HID to control the specific GUI volume on Windows?

Tags: usb, uac, hid

I have a USB(1.1) audio project using a MCU with the USB HID to control the Host(Windows 10)

volume, this project combine with a UAC class and HID class.

I have successfully used the consumer page(0x09) to control Windows volume up/down, but now

I need to control specific Windows applications volume, Is there a way to use the USB HID to

control the specific applications volume on Windows ?

specific like a media play, or a brower playing yourbe music, or a

skype phone call volume, you can set every single volume via Windows

Sound Mixer

the follow is part of my hid report descriptor

```
0x05, 0x0C,      // Usage Page (Consumer)
0x09, 0x01,      // Usage(Consumer Control)
0xA1, 0x01,      // Collection(Application )
0x85, 0x01,      // Report ID (1)
0x15, 0x00,      // Logical Minimum(0x0 )
0x25, 0x01,      // Logical Maximum(0x1 )
0x09, 0xE2,      // Usage(play back Mute)       //1
0x09, 0xE9,      // Usage(Volume Increment)     //2
0x09, 0xB5,      // Usage(Scan Next Track)      //4
0x09, 0xEA,      // Usage(Volume Decrement)     //8
0x09, 0xB6,      // Usage(Scan Previous Track)  //10
0x09, 0xCD,      // Usage(Play/Pause)           //20
```

thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "specific GUI(user interface) volume"?

Comment: thanks for your commet, sorry, i did'nt discribe clear, specific like a media play, or a brower playing yourbe music, or a skype phone call volume, you can set every single volume via Windows Sound Mixer, but I don't know there is a way using the HID to control each of them rather than control the whole system volume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [document available](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/hardware/design/dn613956(v=vs.85)) that lists **HID Usages** from **Consumer Page (0x0C)** that are supported in Windows 8. Regarding volume controls it lists:

| Usage | Usage name | Usage type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0xE0 | Volume | Linear Control (LC) |
| 0xE2 | Mute | On/Off Control (OOC) |
| 0xE3 | Bass | Linear Control (LC) |
| 0xE4 | Treble | Linear Control (LC) |
| 0xE5 | Bass Boost | On/Off Control (OOC) |
| 0xE9 | Volume Increment | Re-trigger Control (RTC) |
| 0xEA | Volume Decrement | Re-trigger Control (RTC) |
| 0x0152 | Bass Increment | Re-trigger Control (RTC) |
| 0x0153 | Bass Decrement | Re-trigger Control (RTC) |
| 0x0154 | Treble Increment | Re-trigger Control (RTC) |
| 0x0155 | Treble Decrement | Re-trigger Control (RTC) |

AFAIK that is what we got out of the box on Windows.

"15 Consumer Page (0x0C)" chapter of the [HID Usage Tables](https://www.usb.org/hid) spec has some additional audio usages that seems not handled by Windows:

| Usage ID | Usage Name | Usage Types |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0xE1 | Balance | LC |
| 0xE6 | Surround Mode | OSC |
| 0xE7 | Loudness | OOC |
| 0xE8 | MPX | OOC |
| 0x0150 | Balance Right | RTC |
| 0x0151 | Balance Left | RTC |

If you really want to do "per-application volume" thing then you can report your volume knobs in **Vendor-Defined Usage Page** (any value in 0xFF00-0xFFFF range) and write a custom user-mode tool (or [HID event filter driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/microsoft/windows-driver-samples/kmdf-filter-driver-for-a-hid-device/) for your VID/PID) that will read that data and do what you want:

- enumerate audio sessions via [IAudioSessionEnumerator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/audiopolicy/nn-audiopolicy-iaudiosessionenumerator)
- cast [IAudioSessionControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/audiopolicy/nn-audiopolicy-iaudiosessioncontrol) to [ISimpleAudioVolume](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/audioclient/nn-audioclient-isimpleaudiovolume)
- call [ISimpleAudioVolume::SetMasterVolume](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/audioclient/nf-audioclient-isimpleaudiovolume-setmastervolume) method to set per-application (AudioSession) volume.